# Android How to connect to FTP?

Tags: java, android, ftp

i am trying to connect to a server through a apache FTP:

```
public boolean ftpConnect(String host, String user, String pass){
        try {
            ftpClient = new FTPClient();
            ftpClient.connect(host);
            if(FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftpClient.getReplyCode())){
                boolean status = ftpClient.login(user, pass);
                ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                return status;
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            Log.d("FTP", "Error: could not connect to socket " + host );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("FTP", "Error: could not connect to host " + host );
        }
        return false;
}
```

If i am connected to internet through WI-FI, the above code is working, but if i am connected through 3G is not working. I've already added the permission for Internet on the
manifest. I haven't found an explanation for this on google.

Comment: Perhaps your 3g provider doesn't allow ftp on their network.

Comment: But i tested this app on 2 providers from 2 different countries and haven't worked.

Comment: I'm already using ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try {
    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(Your host Url));
    ftpClient.login(loginName, password);
    System.out.println("status :: " + ftpClient.getStatus());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also, see my answer here: [Track FTP upload data in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753919/track-ftp-upload-data-in-android/8755556#8755556).