# How to show progress bar while uploading files to amazon s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, progress-bar

I am uploading files to `Amazon S3` bucket and that is working perfectly fine. Now I want to show the progress while uploading them, I have research everywhere but none of them is working. Below is the code for uploading file to `Amazon S3` bucket-

On Spring boot controller-

```
private static final String UPLOAD_FILE_URL = "/uploadImages.htm";
@RequestMapping(value = UPLOAD_FILE_URL, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView uploadImagesRequest(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] files, @RequestParam("filename") String title, HttpServletRequest request) {      
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");             
        if(awsUploadImageInterface.uploadImage(filess, title, request)) {               
            model.addObject("successMsg", "Banner Image Is Added Successfully");
        }
        return "index";     
    }
```

Upload Image Functionality-

```
@Override
    public boolean uploadImage(MultipartFile[] file, String title, HttpServletRequest request) {        
        boolean result = false;             
        S3BucketUtility s3client = new S3BucketUtility();
        InputStream Is;
        String key;
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream propstream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("s3.properties");      
        try {
            prop.load(propstream);          
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Properties File Exception in AWS Connection Class: " + e);
        }               
        try {
            for (int j = 0; j < file.length; j++) {
                if (file[j].getSize() != 0) {                       
                    Is = file[j].getInputStream();                  
                    String fileext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file[j].getOriginalFilename());                 
                    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(prop.getProperty("acceskey"), prop.getProperty("scretkey"));
                    String BucketName = prop.getProperty("bucketName");
                    key = title.concat(".").concat(fileext);
                    ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
                    metadata.setContentLength(Long.valueOf(Is.available()));
                    metadata.setContentType("image".concat("/").concat(fileext));
                    s3client.uploadfile(credentials, BucketName, key, Is, metadata);                                        
                }
            }       
        }catch (AmazonClientException e) {
            return result;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();           
        } 
        return result;      
    }
```

Hope anyone can help me how to show the progress as I am unable to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of asking whole code for functionality just ask what problem you are facing.

Comment: I have tried some codes but the progress is showing after uploading so how can I achieve that progress at same time.

Comment: I think here is your answer: [Stack Overflow: How to get the progress status of the file uploaded to Amazon S3 using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11955036/11758843)